# Joomla : MorfeoShow inside module

Tags: image, animation, joomla, module, image-gallery

i am using joomla 1.6 with morfeoshow 1.2 extension.
I need to add new gallery  inside home page modulethis time not inside article, i dont know if it's supported or not.
My question is how can i add morfeoshow gallery inside a module in joomla 1.6.

Thanks

Comment: How are you currently including it in an article? And secondly, why are you using Joomla 1.6? It's old and not supported anymore. You should upgrade to Joomla 2.5.

Comment: thanks for the answer, in article gallery is called by ID exp { morfeo 33}

Answer (score 1):

Morfeoshow is no longer supported and doesn't have a module to let you implement that inside an article or a module position. You have to try another component like [Phoca gallery](http://www.phoca.cz/download/category/1-phoca-gallery-component)

That will be also good to update your joomla installation to 2.5.22 to avoid security issues.

Comment: thanks, the problem is with modules inside articles every thing is working well thanks i'll try Phoca gallery

Comment: Please check also this tutorial that may help you: [How do you put a module inside an article?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)

Comment: thanks ammanuel, problem resolved by creating animation with an extarnal flash tools then embeded to joomla.